# usercreationform can not change password label

Tags: django

I can't change password1,password2 labels from UserCreationForm class. The email address seems to be ok. What could be the problem?

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','password1','password2',)
        labels = {
            'email' : 'Email address',
            'password1' : 'Password',
            'password2' : 'Confirmation Password',
        }
```

Comment: `password1` and `password2` are not fields of the model, and thus are *not* constructed to the `ModelForm` logic.

Answer (score 1):

`password1` and `password2` are not fields of the model, and thus are *not* constructed to the `ModelForm` logic. This thus means that if you change the `labels` of these form fields, it will not make any difference, since these are *not* constructed through the meta-class of the `ModelForm`.

You can simply respecify the fields and now with a different label:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

UserModel = get_user_model()

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Confirmation Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
        strip=False,
        help_text=_('Enter the same password as before, for verification.'),
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email',)
        labels = {
            'email' : 'Email address'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is overriding `__init__`:

```py
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        labels = {
            'email' : 'Email address',
            'password1' : 'Password',
            'password2' : 'Confirmation Password',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for k, v in self.Meta.labels.items():
            self[k].label = v
```

Note that you don't need to specify `model` and `fields` unless you intend to change them as they'll be inherited from `UserCreationForm.Meta`.